# PHP Convert String to Duration

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Using *PHP*, *MySQLi*.

I am selecting a string from a MySQL database and saving it to a variable called `$queryTime`, I'd like to modify how this string is displayed on screen. When I `print_r($queryTime);` I see;

> 01:25:24

When I `var_dump($queryTime)` I see;

> string(8) "01:25:24"

Is there any way I can display the string in a time duration format - something like;

> 1 hour, 25 minutes, 24 seconds

Presumably because the database field is stored as a `varchar` and not a `time-stamp` things are more complicated? Unfortunately I don't have access to modify the database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You must convert the string to a date (`strtotime()` function), and then you can manage the date and the time easily

Comment: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ is a library that does all this common calcultations for you

Comment: If you want to make duration format directly from the time string you can use explode() function and create your string

Comment: it's just a string. you can always just `explode` on `:`, count how many parts you get, and use that to figure out which is seconds/minutes/hours/days etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simple work on that string, if the format is always the same:

```
$queryTime = '01:25:24';

$parts = explode(':', $queryTime);
$parts[0] .= ' hours';
$parts[1] .= ' minutes';
$parts[2] .= ' seconds';

//01 hours, 25 minutes, 24 seconds
echo implode(', ', $parts);
```